# svgElement isn't working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, svg

html tag

```
<svg  width="550px" height="300px">
    <g transform="translate(275, 150)"> 
        <circle id="mySquare" cx="0" cy="0" r="10" style=" fill: orange; />
    </g>
</svg>
```

js script

```
mySquare.currentTheta += 0.3;
mySquare.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setRotate(mySquare.currentTheta, 0, 0);
```

this script is working in IE9

but in chrome, not working

chrome don't suport svgElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) before to get a hold of the respective element:

```
var mySquare = document.getElementById( 'mySquare' );
mySquare.currentTheta += 0.3;
mySquare.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setRotate(mySquare.currentTheta, 0, 0);
```

The feature/bug, that all elements with ids get a global variable with that id, is not present in all browsers.

Comment: howabout createSVGTransform() api?

Comment: @user2010300 Sorry. Can't find any compatibility table for this.